# 画面の上に小さいメニュー画面を置く

Tags: swift, xcode

初心者です。
storyboardを使って、画面の上に覆いかぶさる様な小さいメニュー画面を作りたいと思っています。
ハンバーガーメニューの様な画面なのですが、画面遷移だけでもstoryboardで作ることは可能でしょうか？
もし可能なら、大体の工程を教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

一番簡単なのは、セグエ(present as popover)を使うことです。
ただし解像度の低い端末では、present modallyと同じ動きになるのでご期待には添えないかもしれません。(とはいえ、解像度の低い端末では、小さいメニューを出しても視認性が悪いので素直に諦めるほうが良いかもしれません）

Answer (score 0):

セグエ(Present Modally)を使い、PresentationをOverCurrentContextに設定し、Backgroundに透過色を用いる方法があります。

これはセグエ(Present as Popover)とは違い、解像度の低い端末でも関係なく動作します